# Finding a hidden extension in a file path

Tags: .net, vb.net, file

What is the best way to figure out if a file’s path contains a hidden extension, for example when malware attempts to hide .exe like “LegitimateFile.pdf.exe”.

Here is what I have tried so far, but there are several issues.  First of all, the extension may not always be 3 characters, for example .js. The other issue is that some legitimate files will be named “GoodInstaller.V2.5.exe”, so that creates issues as well.

```
Dim HiddenExtension As Boolean = False
Dim firstExtension As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ProcessPath)
Dim secondExtension As String = Path.GetExtension(firstExtension)
If secondExtension.StartsWith(".") And secondExtension.Length = 4 And secondExtension Like ".*" Then HiddenExtension = True
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to find. I'm not quite sure which part of "LegitimateFile.pdf.exe" you call "hidden extension".

Comment: The .exe is the real extension, but will be hidden if the Windows folders options "Hide extensions for known file types" is checked, so it will appear as though the extension is .pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of all executable-like extensions (e.g. .exe, .bat, ..) and a list of all document-like extensions (e.g. .doc, .pdf ,...) and then you can depend on these lists to determine if a file is dangerous. Here is a code sample:

```
Function IsDangerous(filename As String) As Boolean

    Dim first_extension = Path.GetExtension(filename)

    If first_extension = String.Empty Or Not IsExecutableExtension(first_extension) Then Return False

    Dim filename_without_first_extension As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename)

    Dim second_extension As String = Path.GetExtension(filename_without_first_extension)

    If second_extension = String.Empty Or Not IsDocumentExtension(second_extension) Then Return False

    Return True

End Function

Function IsExecutableExtension(extension As String) As Boolean
    Dim executable_extensions = New String() {".exe", ".bat"} 'We need to add more items to this array
    Return executable_extensions.Contains(extension)
End Function

Function IsDocumentExtension(extension As String) As Boolean
    Dim document_extensions = New String() {".pdf", ".doc", ".xls"} 'We need to add more items to this array
    Return document_extensions.Contains(extension)
End Function
```

And you use it like this:

```
Dim dangerous = IsDangerous("test.pdf.exe")
```

Comment: Thank you!  Yeah, that will work, but I was hoping to not have to list all of the possible extensions because there are so many possibilities.  But that might be the only way to do it.

Comment: I think you should use a regular expression for this kind of problem. Mentioning all kind of possible file extensions is not a good approach.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen, How can a regular expression match items that have almost nothing in common? Can you provide an example of such regular expression?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sorry, I think I misunderstand the problem. Your solution is good. All possible executable extensions must be declared.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  Thank you for your help!